# Android studio layout editor always landscape?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-editor

My app is going to be just landscape. But each time I need to set the xml layout editor to landscape mode when I start editing a layout. How can I have my xml layout editor always stay in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1):

you must build layouts on Landscape variation.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Hz4.png)

so you can choose this on top bar of android studio xml design.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking if there's a way to lock a design to show on Landscape when you open the visual editor (which, to the best of my knowledge, there's not).

Comment: yes, but in this case, when your layout be dedicate for landscape, visual editor will open it on landscape mode.Now it will be work like that @Saj wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it exactly like @alireza daryani suggested.

1. Open your `layout.xml`
2. Choose `Create landscape variation`

[image: Create landscape variation]

3. If you don't need the porttrait variation delete it

"Create landscape variation" will create a `layout-land` folder in your project so Android Studio will know that these layouts shall be previewed in landscape mode. Into this folder will be an exact copy your origin layout. In my case I just wanted landscape layout for my app, so I deleted the origins. Works perfect.